# Wrong symbols in the buffer using GetWindowText

Tags: c++, winapi

There is combo box with two items and button on the main window. Combobox:

```
HWND hCombo;
hCombo = CreateWindow(L"COMBOBOX", L"combobox",
       WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_SORT | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST,
       10, 55, 232, 500, hWnd, 0, hInstance, 0);

const wchar_t *langEnglish = L"English";
const wchar_t *langRussian = L"Russian";
SendMessage(hCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)langEnglish);
SendMessage(hCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)langRussian);
SendMessage(hCombo, CB_SETCURSEL, 0, 0);
```

I am trying to get selected item text in the **WndProc** by clicking on the button:

```
case WM_COMMAND:                                            
{
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {  
        case IDC_BUTTON_OK:
            wchar_t buf[10];
            hCombo = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_COMBO);
            GetDlgItemText(hCombo, IDC_COMBO, (LPWSTR)buf, 10);
            MessageBox(hWnd, (LPCWSTR)buf, NULL, MB_OK);
            break;
    }

} break;
```

I am using breakpoint in the MSVS2010 to see **buf** variable. It contains **chinese** symbols!!! Message box shows *empty* message (With the title "**Error**"). I want to see english text. What is wrong?

This code

```
nIndex = SendMessage(hCombo, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
SendMessage(hCombo, CB_GETLBTEXT, nIndex, (LPARAM)buf);
```

fills **buf** with the same chinese symbols

**SOLUTION:** 
hCombo = CreateWindow(L"COMBOBOX", L"combobox",
       WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_SORT | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST,
       10, 55, 232, 500, hWnd, **(HMENU)IDC_COMBO**, hInstance, 0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get currently selected item from `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` styled combo box you need [`CB_GETCURSEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get selection index and then [`CB_GETLBTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the string.

Comment: This code: nIndex = SendMessage(hCombo, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
SendMessage(hCombo, CB_GETLBTEXT, nIndex, (LPARAM)buf);  fills the buf with the same chinese symbols

Comment: The characters you refer to as Chinese are in fact an uninitialized buffer. The first character is perhaps zero and this makes the returned value just an empty string. This in turn has its own reason - wrong handle etc.

Comment: Well then - you have empty string returned. Why? Wrong handle or no selection (items were removed by the time of the call) etc.